# How to check whether h1 tag exist in a prticular div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check whether h1 tag exists inside a div with id = "test". How can I use the JQuery length property to achieve this?

Comment: $("#test").find("h1")

Comment: Are you open to other methods, or just want to use the length property?

Comment: @aorfevre Post that as an answer!

Comment: Is it possible with length property? I already got a solution with the normal find method.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do a jQuery check :

```
$("#test").find("h1").length
```

if size > 0, then you have one or more h1 tags

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to achieve what you described. I would do:

```
if($("#test h1").length !== 0) {
    // h1 exists from within #test
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the `!== 0`, as zero is _falsey_

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').filter('h1').length > 0
```